# Why do I get validation error "required" on datepicker when its not empty and has value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, yup, react-hook-form

I am using @material-ui/pickers, react-hook-form and yup for validation.

I always get validation error that the field is required even though I filled it and populated it with date and the date is registering correctly. I only want the error to pop out when the user hasn't selected any date.

Here is the codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-snow-r5teh

The validation works just as expected on another field, so I don't think there is any errors in my code?

```
const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
  country: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup.date().required()
});

  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState<Date | null | undefined>(
    null
  );
        <Controller
          render={({ field }) => (
            <DatePicker
              {...field}
              inputVariant="outlined"
              disableFuture
              fullWidth
              openTo="year"
              format="ddd/MM/YYYY"
              error={!!errors.age}
              helperText={errors.age?.message}
              views={["year", "month", "date"]}
              value={selectedDate}
              onChange={(newValue) => handleDateChange(newValue?.toDate())}
            />
          )}
          name="age"
          control={control}
        />
```

Comment: what actually bothering you? what kind of behavior you need and what you get instead?

Comment: @ArtemVadimovichSolovev form is not submitting, because age field is not passing the ` age: yup.date().required()` validation even when you chose the date. I only want to get the error if the field is empty.